# Express serve all files of a folder recursively

Tags: node.js, express, subdirectory

When I do this:

```
app.use('/assets', cacheControl, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets'), { maxAge: 30 }));
```

I can't access the files of `path.join(__dirname, 'assets/fonts')`

I wonder whether there is a *recursive folder server component* by `express` or not.

Comment: `express.static()` works with nested paths, so there's some other issue causing this. Are you getting 404 responses for the font files? And by which URL are you retrieving them?

Comment: @robertklep:Yes that's working there was another issue. thanks.

Comment: To look at the access control of your folder